# Set 'data-persist' attribute through formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, formtastic

I have,

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @house, @note] do |f| %>
```

which gives me,

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/houses/10975/notes" class="formtastic note" id="new_note" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

I want,

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/houses/10975/notes" class="formtastic note" id="new_note" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" data-persist = "garlic" >
```

Please take note of 'data-persist' attribute.

Is there any way to add such data-attribute to form tag through formtastic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`semantic_form_for` accepts the same options as `form_for` so for your problem, the solution would be

```
semantic_form_for [:admin, @house, @note], html: { data: { persist: 'garlic' } }
```

If for some reason, it is showing `data=persistgarlic` instead of what you expected, try the following

```
semantic_form_for [:admin, @house, @note], html: { 'data-persist' => 'garlic' }
```

Comment: I tried :html => {:data-persist => 'garlic'}, however it did not work. Do you see any specific reason? Why it did not work ?

Comment: `:data-persist` is not a valid symbol. use `'data-persist'` or `:"data-persist"`